# How to draw a photoelectron spectrum with ionization energies?

Tags: spectroscopy

I understand the basic concepts of the photoelectron spectrum. However, say I am instructed to draw the PES graph for Silicon. I know how to figure out the relative peaks based on its configuration. But when arranging them on the graph, how can I accurately place them where they should be in ionization energy? That is, the x-axis is labeled 300.0, 200.0, 100.0, etc. Without any other information (and the usage of a periodic table only) how do I know where to put the peaks among the increments? Is there a way to figure out the ionization energies for each peak?

If this is NOT possible, please explain why.

Comment: It would seem that you're asking about x-ray photoelectron spectroscopy.  A photon of defined energy is used to ionize electrons in the atoms/molecules of the sample. The kinetic energy of the electrons is the energy of the photon minus the binding energy of the electron. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy

Comment: Thanks. But if I don't have information on what the energy of the photon or electrons are? If the instruction is simple "draw the pes of X element" and the only info I get is 1) already labeled increments on the x-axis and 2) a periodic table, if relevant, then how in the world would I place them appropriately?

Comment: Have a look at the *units* on your axis, if in electron volts (eV) then the energy is in the x-ray region. The lowest energy electrons (1s) will have the largest values as it takes more energy to ionise these. Thus you can get the ordering of  electrons in different orbitals, but without looking up some more information I don't see how you can get accurate values.